# Bluetooth not working on Inspiron 9400

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bluetooth, dell-inspiron

It used to work when I had Windows XP installed, but now, with Windows 7, it isn't even showing up in my device manager.

I tried updating the drivers but that didn't fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Install the "Toshiba Bluetooth Stack" software.  You should be able to find it on Dell's website.

Answer (score 0):

Check your software switch (if there is any with Fn+ something), check your hardware switch (like a small switch for wifi+bt) and check your bios.

Comment: Yep, did that, it is enabled in the BIOS and i set the WiFi hotkey (Fn +F2) to Bluetooth only and nothing happens....However i should mention that i am using a wireless Microsoft mouse and keyboard with a bluetooth dongle....not sure if that would affect anything.  I removed the dongle and the internal module still is unresponsive.

Comment: Remove the dongle and remove everything related from the Device Manager from the control panel. Do a reboot, it should reinstall the drivers and reset everything back (no, dont plug your bluetooth back until you did the reboot and it finishes)

Answer (score 0):

CChriss is right, but the answrr is rather brief and I do not want to edit his post too much. Soo....

In order to use a network you need to load the **driver** for the network card and the relevant protocol to use it. (e.g. TCP/IP). These days those are shipped with Windows. No need to actually download anything but the NICs drivers.

For bluetooth this is similar: You need the **drivers** and you need the matching **protocol stack**.  This one is not free.

There are two ways to acquire the stack:

1. Buy it (expensive)
2. Get the one from Dells website (where Dell already paid for it so they could use it with many of their computers). Depending on the EULA this might or might not be legal.

Just add add some more background: To have what you expect